# Python script partially inactive after few hours - Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, telegram, gpio

I wrote a Python script for the Raspberry Pi in order to monitor changes of 4 GPIO inputs, write them into a databse and send a message to my phone via a telegram bot.

Everything works fine, except that after a couple of hours, some processes of the script shut down. The script is still running (knwoing from a log file), but especially the GPIO event detect and the telegram bot API stop working. This mostly occurs over night.

Because it works perfectly fine for the first few hours after startup, I guess it shouldn't be a bug in the program, but you never know.

I started up the script via `rc.local`, but switched to `System.d` for running on startup instead. Works fine for that.

So in a nutshell: Script runs fine, but after a couple of hours some functions in the script become inactive (GPIO event detect, log messages, telegram API - kinda feels like the Pi is falling asleep).

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

#Import libraries
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import telepot
import MySQLdb
import os.path
import logging
import datetime

#start logging
logfile = '/home/pi/Betrieb/logs/log_'+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")
logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile,level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
logging.debug('=========================================================')
logging.debug('Logging started!')

#initialize connection to Telegram bot
bot = telepot.Bot('##########################################')

#Connect to MySQL-database
con = MySQLdb.connect('localhost',"root","###########","################")
c = con.cursor()

###########################################################################################################

class User:

    def __init__(self, id, name, user_id, enable):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.chat_id = user_id
        self.enable = enable

class Machine:

    def __init__(self, id, number, name, pin, enable):
        self.id = id
        self.number = number
        self.name = name
        self.pin = pin
        self.enable = enable

###########################################################################################################
def my_callback(pin):
    c.execute("SELECT name FROM machines WHERE pin=%s" % pin)
    con.commit()
    data = c.fetchall()
    for set in data:
        machine_name=set[0]
        ### Attention: multiple sets with same ID can exist



    if GPIO.input(pin):
        print "Rising edge detected "+str(pin)

        string = "INSERT INTO malfunction(machine_name,machine_pin,status) VALUES('%s',%s,1)" % (machine_name,pin)
        c.execute(string)
        con.commit()

        for i in range(0,len(user)):        
            if user[i].enable:
                bot.sendMessage(user[i].chat_id,"Stoerung "+ machine_name)
                print "Sent message to", user[i].name               
                logging.debug('Detected malfunction on Pin %s and sent message to %s', str(pin), user[i].name)


    else:  
        print "Falling edge detected on "+str(pin)      

        string = "INSERT INTO malfunction(machine_name,machine_pin,status) VALUES('%s',%s,0)" % (machine_name,pin)
        c.execute(string)
        con.commit()

        for i in range(0,len(user)):
            if user[i].enable:
                bot.sendMessage(user[i].chat_id,"Stoerung behoben "+ machine_name) 
                print "Sent message to", user[i].name   

                logging.debug('Solved malfunction on Pin %s and sent message to %s', str(pin), user[i].name)



def updateData():
    global machine
    global user

    logging.debug('Update data.')

    #Update user data    
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM telegram_users")
    con.commit()
    data = c.fetchall()        

    user = []
    del user[:]

    for set in data:
        newUser = User(set[0],set[1],set[2],set[3])
        user.append(newUser)    


    #Update machine data
    try: 
        machine
    except NameError:
        machine = []
    else:

        for i in range(0,len(machine)):
            if machine[i].enable:
                GPIO.remove_event_detect(machine[i].pin)
        del machine[:]

    c.execute("SELECT * FROM machines")
    con.commit()
    data = c.fetchall()        

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    for set in data:
        # 0 = id / 1 = number / 2 = name / 3 = pin / 4 = enable #
        newMachine = Machine(set[0],set[1],set[2],set[3],set[4])
        machine.append(newMachine)
        if set[4]:
            GPIO.setup(set[3], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)    
            GPIO.add_event_detect(set[3], GPIO.BOTH, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=300)

            logging.debug('Added Event Detect on Pin %s', set[3])

###########################################################################################################

updateData()

logging.debug('Initial Update finished. Start looping.')

Counter = 0
while True:
    Counter +=1
    if Counter == 600:
        logging.debug('Still running!')
        Counter = 0


    time.sleep(1);
    lockfile = "/home/pi/Betrieb/lockfiles/request_update"
    if os.path.isfile(lockfile):
        os.remove(lockfile)
        updateData()
        print "Data updated."
        logging.debug('Deleted lockfile and updated data.')
```